# PHP: deduplicate an array based on a matching substring of unixtime

Tags: php, arrays, file-io

I have a list of files that contain an IP address and the unix TS.
I need to get a deduplicated list of files, but only the latest one for that host (this needs to be based on the unix ts in the filename, not the file's actual ts).

sample data:

```
192.168.1.6_1352405854.xml  192.168.1.6_1352408700.xml  192.168.1.6_1352409088.xml   192.168.189.14_1352409088.xml
192.168.1.6_1352407188.xml  192.168.1.6_1352408715.xml  192.168.1.6_1352409520.xml   192.168.189.14_1352409520.xml
192.168.1.6_1352407248.xml  192.168.1.6_1352408796.xml  192.168.1.6_1352409601.xml   192.168.189.14_1352409601.xml
192.168.1.6_1352407311.xml  192.168.1.6_1352408830.xml  192.168.1.6_1352412001.xml   192.168.189.14_1352412001.xml
192.168.1.6_1352407329.xml  192.168.1.6_1352408907.xml  192.168.1.6_1352415602.xml   192.168.189.14_1352415602.xml
192.168.1.6_1352408608.xml  192.168.1.6_1352409018.xml  192.168.189.14_1352409018.xml
```

So the expected result would be an array of filenames only listing the latest file from each IP.

Something like:

192.168.1.6_1352415602.xml

192.168.1.14_1352415602.xml

In my code, I have to loop through a directory structure and pull filenames and directories.

The directories would be a site name that makes up a left menu.

The files would be under those menu items as a hyperlinked hostname (but I only need the latest file information from each host)

```
// Get directory list and (natural) sort it alphabetically (ignoring case)
        $glob = "xml/vpnm/*";
        $dirs = glob($glob,GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        foreach ($dirs as $d){
            $tmp[basename($d)] = basename($d);
        }
        natcasesort($tmp);
        $dirs = array_keys($tmp);
        foreach($dirs as $dir){
            $dir = basename($dir);
            $sitename = preg_replace('/_/', ' ', $dir);
            echo "<h3><a href='#'>$sitename</a></h3>";
            echo '<div>';
                // Get list of hosts in the xml/ directory based on the file name
                $year = date("Y");
                $month = date("m");
                $basepath = "xml/vpnm/$dir/$year/$month";
// note - preg_find is an include file, not a php function
 $files = preg_find('/\.xml$/D', "xml/vpnm/$dir", PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE);
                foreach ($files as $f){
                    // echo " F= $f \n";
                    $tmp[basename($f)] = basename($f);
                }
                natcasesort($tmp);
                $files = array_keys($tmp);
                natsort($files);
// do something here to deduplicate and only include the latest files.
foreach($files as $file) {
...
```

Comment: Have you attempted solving it and hit a roadblock at something specific?

Comment: @xbones. I really just have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dirlist = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
$results = array();
foreach($dirlist as $file){
    if($file->getExtension() !='xml') continue;
    $parts = explode('_',$file->getBasename());
    if(isset($results[$parts[0]])){
        if($file->getBasename() > $results[$parts[0]]->getBasename()){
            $results[$parts[0]] = $file;
        }
    } else {
        $results[$parts[0]] = $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect...thank you SO much! Didn't even know about RecursiveIteratorIterator, so thanks for the help :-)